# In Oracle 11g, how to change the order of the results of a sql without "order by"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Now I have a very simple SQL: 
select * from table A

I know the results will be sorted by "rowid"(I'm not very sure, I'm a freshman).
And Oracle will not guarantee the order of the results of a SQL without "order by".

Here's my question:

Once I've got results in such order:   ....A...B....

Now I want the results in this order:  ....B...A....

Just make B before A is OK.
How to do this?

Notice 1: This is an experiment. Please be patient to think about my question.

Notice 2: Do not change the primary key of any record, and do not use any DDL, and use the same SQL "select * from table A".

Notice 3:

```
create table A(id NUMBER(20) primary key, name VARCHAR2(30));
insert into A values(1,'one');
insert into A values(2,'two');
select * from A;
```

What I've tried : update, insert ,delete some records, which do not work.

Comment: There is *one*, exactly *one* tool you can use that gives a *guarantee* on the order in which results are returned. Anything else is mere coincidence and is *not* guaranteed. And you've ruled out that one tool. So this question isn't answerable.

Comment: Sorry, I made my question unclear.

Comment: No, your question was clear. It's just that there isn't an answer available, because you're rejecting the one facility that is available that controls the order in which results are returned. If you've ruled out the only thing that will actually work, we can't help you.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

Given this requirement:

> *Do not change the SQL `select * from table A`.* 
>   *Change the table A to change the results order*

the answer is a clear and definite: this is **not** possible.

---

(Keeping my initial answer as a reference)

"*I know the results will be sorted by `rowid`*" - no, they are ***not***.

The rows will be returned in any order the database thinks is the most efficient.

There is no, absolutely no, guarantee that rows are returned in any specific order **unless** you specify an `ORDER BY`.

The ***ONLY*** way to get a specific order **is** to use an `ORDER BY`.

If you want `'B'` to come before `'A'` then simply do a descending order:

```
select * 
from table_A
order by some_col DESC
```

You can put more logic into the `ORDER BY` operator by applying expressions or functions. If you e.g. want to list `'B'` at the top and everything else after that in alphabetical order, you can do something like this:

```
select *
from table_a
order by 
        case 
          when some_col = 'B' then 0 
          else 1
        end, 
        some_col
```

Comment: I know without "order by" the order of results cannot be guaranteed.
But it's some kind of stable.
What I want to know is HOW TO CHANGE the order.
Please give some practical advice.
I need a repeatable simple experiment.

Comment: @user3030336 Not it's ***NOT*** "some kind of stable" - it's completely unpredictable. And I gave you an example on how to order `B` before `A`. See my edit for a more complex example.

Comment: Sorry, I made my question unclear.
Do not change the SQL "select * from table A".
Change the table A to change the results order.

Comment: @user3030336: then the answer to your question is simple: that is **not** possible. You can **not** change the order of a result without using `order by´. Full stop.

Answer (score 1):

You keep trying to "clarify" your question.  As best I can understand it, you're attempting to present a "puzzler" of some sort.  But your puzzler is nonsensical.  What I think you are missing is an understanding of "WHY" the rows are being returned in the order you inserted them.  When you understand that, you'll have a better appreciation of what your question is actually asking, and why you won't be able to solve it.

If you 
1) create a standard Oracle table "A" with PK ID and one (or more) other columns and

2) insert just a couple rows (e.g. less data than will fill a datablock),

3) do no subsequent indexing, moves, reorgs, compression, etc

then yes, all existing implementations of Oracle will resolve SELECT * FROM A by returning your two rows in the same order you inserted them.

This is because 
1) current Oracle implementations will write new records to an empty datablock in the order they were received and

2) subsequent SELECT * FROM A, if there is no index which offers a better plan, will cause a full-table-scan.  Since all of your data will be in a single datablock, and current Oracle implementations read data within a block sequentially, "SELECT * FROM A" will "stably" return rows in the order you inserted them.

In that context, your puzzler seems to be: can a person issue INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements against TABLE A such that current Oracle implementations will execute "SELECT * FROM TABLE A" and return your two rows in reverse order.  Such a challenge is trivially (and really only) solved by, e.g., deleting your two rows and re-inserting them with the ID=2 row first and ID=1 row second.  But your statement "Do not change the primary key of any record" indicates that deleting/re-inserting isn't an option.  In which case, yes, you're asking for the impossible, even from a puzzling perspective: your challenge is to wave a magic wand at Oracle such that it will start reading rows within the same datafile from end-to-start.

ETA: You also disallowed DDL; otherwise, you could do an amusing hack like this to get the desired effect:

```
create table A(id NUMBER(5) primary key, name VARCHAR2(10))
partition by list (id)
(partition p1 values (2),
 partition p2 values (1));

insert into A values(1,'one');

insert into A values(2,'two');

select * from a;


ID    NAME       
---- ---------
2     two        
1     one
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's quite enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Only
    ORDER BY 
is  there for the work. But you can do the required arrangement by making a simple **function** with the logic you want behind the format of the returned rows and use that function.